# FaceBook signup Show error

Tags: php

i have making Facebook signup in php.when i cliked on Facebook login btn they show me this error "Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"

this is config.php file code

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";

    $FB = new \Facebook\Facebook([

        'app_id' => '571388466554956',
        'app_secret' => '8381c3ba6df5f1d44ab8643be299e8dd',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'

    ]);

    $helper = $FB->getRedirectLoginHelper();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK The first step I think is to download the latest version of the Facebook SDK.  Local tests showed this to me.